# Default values for lambda in Sparse Group Lasso(SGL) in R?

Tags: r

How are lambdas chosen by the SGL package if left blank? I am referring to the comment below in the pdf manual.

> "A user speciﬁed sequence of lambda values for ﬁtting. We recommend
>   leaving this NULL and letting SGL self-select values."

Answer (score 2):

By default it creates a sequence of lambda values in which the maximum lambda is the maximum lambda value possible (see grplasso package and lambda.max function for further details), and the minimum lambda is a percentage of lambda max.